# Highlighting words in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, colors, editing

Is there a way to highlight all the occurrence of some words in Visual Studio?

There are several plug-ins of this kind in vim (e.g. https://github.com/lfv89/vim-interestingwords), so I am wondering if there was such a thing for VS. I googled a bit but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: I just tried `Ctrl-F` and enabled Regex (`Alt-E`) entered `word1|word2` and this seems to work just fine without the need for any extension.

Comment: In vim, you're not dependant of the volatile find. You may tag several words and still search into the source file. Each tagged word has a different color, so that it is easier to figure out where, for example, a variable is defined and used, where a function or method is called etc.

Comment: Just my opinion but I believe VS Intellisense already does a decent job for the use cases you describe. If you put the cursor on a variable it will highlight all uses; same goes for methods, etc. In any case this is about personal preferences hence I only commented instead of claiming this to be the a definite answer.

Comment: You only may highlight one name at a time, this way, plus the one with the search. If there are tools for this in vim, it probably means that I'm not the only one needing it. A matter of mindset. ;-)